# Matching strings that don't repeat characters in Regex

Tags: php, regex

I'm a total newbie of Regex. What I'm trying to do is to check if a numeric value repeats numbers. They can be anywhere in the string: eg.

```
123456789 -> would return true
987612345 -> true
```

but:

```
122345678 -> would return false because it uses two times the number 2.
182345688 -> false
```

Is it possible to do this with Regex in PHP?

Comment: About what language are we talking about here?

Comment: You want it on client side or server side?

Comment: In PHP (Server side). I've already edited the question.

Comment: Must the two equal chars be consecutive or can they be anywhere in the string?

Comment: @phimuemue They can be anywhere in the string

Answer (score 5):

In case you don't want to use regexes with massive recursive backtracking:

```
$duplicates = count(count_chars($test, 1)) < strlen($test);
```

[Demo](http://codepad.org/fYOeD9Dg)

---

**Edit:**

In case you want to use a regular expression, you only need to find one duplicate and then quit:

```
$duplicates = preg_match('/(.).*\1/', $test);
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/b1XKBT)

Answer (score 2):

Re-appearing characters will return `1`, e.g.:

```
$match = preg_match_all('/(.).*\1/', '121345678', $arr, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

Others will return `0`, e.g.:

```
$match = preg_match_all('/(.).*\1/', '12345678', $arr, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

Therefore (I named it `clean` as in "non-repeating"):

```
$clean = $match == 0;
```

EDIT:
Maybe for explanation: `\1` is a back-reference to the first (and in this case) only pair of `()`-s. So this regex is matched when a character is found "that was already there before that occurrence".

Comment: If asked, what would you consider the minimum string length which is able to trigger a segmentation fault by that regex on a standard PHP compile?

Comment: @hakre: No idea. Guessing from the question the strings won't be that long anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If they can be anywhere in your string, it's not too easy. I assume it is somehow possible using regexp. But I recommend doing it another way:

- extract the single characters from the string into a array of characters
- sort the array
- check if two adjacent characters are the same

Or any equivalent technique. But I think this problem is a bit too complicated to be solved by regexp in an *elegant* manner.

Answer (score 0):

As for regex I'm not 100% sure, but you can do this other way:

```
function hasRepeatingNumbers($number) {
    $numberArray = array_unique(str_split($number));
    if(count($numberArray) != strlen($number)) {
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

In the example above we're removing any duplicate numbers and comparing the length of each variables. If they're differente then it's because we removed duplicate numbers.

Then you should just need to:

```
if(hasRepeatingNumbers('123456789'))
    echo "No repeating numbers";
else
    echo "There are repeating numbers";
```

This should work just as like.

Answer (score 0):

`/(\d)(?=.*\1)/`

Only looks for digits, matches/quits at first duplicate found.
Warning!, this could be slow.

I imagine this would do it
`if ( preg_match( '/(\d)(?=.*\1)/', "your string", $match) ) ..`

This method might cause problems if digits 0-9 are unique and the string is
very long. Theorhetically, it would inspect 10 times the length of the string.

On the other hand, if you have more than 10 digits, there is at least one dup.
So, in a `single pass`, extract up to the first 11 digits. Then you can either
loop through the (up to 11 digits) array elements, or use a hash if PHP does that.
This is the fastest method, it might be a verbose regex (11 capture buffers) but PCRE   can't do variable amount of capture buffers.

Example in Perl (using a hash):

```
$_ = '12asasdf3456789 4 0 asdf 3';

my @found = /
 ^
  [^\d]*
  (\d) [^\d]*(\d?)[^\d]*(\d?)[^\d]*(\d?)[^\d]*(\d?)[^\d]*
  (\d?)[^\d]*(\d?)[^\d]*(\d?)[^\d]*(\d?)[^\d]*(\d?)[^\d]*
  (\d?)
/x;

for (@found) {
   if ($seen{$_}++) {
      print "Found a duplicate: '$_'\n";
      last;
   }
}
```

Output:
`Found a duplicate: '4'`